# Mysql 2 tables use player_id with name from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php & mysql and I'm trying to make a script that gets the distance walked with the player's name. I can get the player's walked distance with his id, but the value for the `player_id` is in a different table.

It looks like this:

```
Table1: player_id | foot (walked distance)

Table2: name | player_id
```

So I want to use the name by the `player_id` in my table.

[Code](http://pastebin.com/9VwC0uAa)

Comment: Its private can't see your code

Comment: you should be able to view it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join both these table.

Just try this code:

```
$query = "SELECT T1.*, T2.name  
          FROM table1 T1
          LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.player_id = T2.player_id
          ORDER BY T2.name  ASC";
```

For more details of JOIN: [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Let me know for more help.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me an empty echo "0 results"; i tried: $sql = "SELECT stats_distances.*, stats_players`.name  
          FROM stats_distances
          LEFT JOIN stats_players ON stats_distances.player_id = stats_players.player_id
          ORDER BY stats_players.name  ASC";

Comment: Welp, i fixed it:  stats_players`.name. there was a ` now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You require a simple join.

```
SELECT Table1.foot, Table2.name
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.player_id =               Table2.player_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join in mysql.

Suppose if you have two tables use this

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.walked distance
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.id=T2.player_id;
```

[Click Here For more  example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$query = "select t1.player_id, t2.name, t1.foot 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.player_id = t2.player_id"
```

If you want to order the player names in alphabetical order then you can additionally use `order by` clause

```
$query = "select t1.player_id, t2.name, t1.foot 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
order by t2.name"
```